# Storing a 2 dimensional Array in PROGMEM

Tags: programming

I am running a Mega 2560 processor board.

I have a large "unsigned char" database currently stored in a 2 dimensional array in SRAM.  I have plenty of room in program memory and need to move the database to PROGMEM.  It appears that the rules around how to use PROGMEM have changed and the documentation does not reflect the change. I have found a way to store the array in PROGMEM and can access the data statically (ARRAY[0,1]).  If I try to access the array dynamically, (ARRAY[var1,var2]), I get junk.

Since I have seen some questions what I mean by "static" and "Dynamic" I gladly add the following examples:

```
//Array initialization

const static unsigned char __attribute__ ((progmem)) Image_1d_Array[234]={
  0x00, 0x0e, 0xf8, 0xff, 0xdf, 0x03, 0xc0, 0x1d, 0x60, 0x1f, 0x60, 0x00, 0x03,
   0xdb, 0x01, 0x00, 0x08, 0xe3, 0x07, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x1e, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00,
   0x00, 0x0e, 0xf0, 0x07, 0xfc, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x39, 0x00, 0x1f, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x03};


void setup:  
  int i;
  char myChar;

//  Static read.  This will give me the correct values  
  Serial.print("Image= "); Serial.println(Image_1d_Array[0],HEX);
  Serial.print("Image= "); Serial.println(Image_1d_Array[1],HEX);
  Serial.print("Image= "); Serial.println(Image_1d_Array[2],HEX);
  Serial.print("Image= "); Serial.println(Image_1d_Array[3],HEX);
  Serial.println("");

//  Dynamic read.  This will give me the junk values  
  for(i = 0; i <=11; i++){
     Serial.print("AImage= ");
     myChar = pgm_read_byte_near(&Image_1d_Array + i);
     Serial.println(myChar,HEX);
    }
```

I can't even get a single dimensional array to work dynamically.

Does anybody understand the new rules to access the array?? The following data structures from the Arduino reference manual are no longer supported

```
prog_char - a signed char (1 byte) -127 to 128
prog_uchar - an unsigned char (1 byte) 0 to 255
prog_int16_t - a signed int (2 bytes) -32,767 to 32,768
prog_uint16_t - an unsigned int (2 bytes) 0 to 65,535
prog_int32_t - a signed long (4 bytes) -2,147,483,648 to * 2,147,483,647.
prog_uint32_t - an unsigned long (4 bytes) 0 to 4,294,967,295
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you mean by the phrases  “access the data statically” and “access the data dynamically”.  You might need to add   a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code so people don't have to waste time guessing what you did or what you meant.   § AFAIK,  “the rules around how to use PROGMEM have changed” is false.

Comment: I tested on an UNO and it works fine if you remove the `&`.

Comment: Accept Edgar Bonnet's answer to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
myChar = pgm_read_byte_near(&Image_1d_Array + i);
```

Here `&Image_1d_Array` is the address of the array. Its type is “pointer
to an array of 234 unsigned chars”. When you add `i` to this pointer,
per the rules of pointer arithmetic, you are actually adding to the
address `i` times the size of the array.

What you actually mean by `&Image_1d_Array` is “the address of the first
element of the array”, which can be written `&Image_1d_Array[0]`. Or you
could rely on the usual “decay to pointer” semantics, and simply write
`Image_1d_Array`, as suggested  in Johnny Mopp's comment.

Now you should have noticed that both `Image_1d_Array` and
`&Image_1d_Array` behave as pointers to the same memory address, only
they have different types. See the
[C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html) and references therein
for more on this distinction.

Note that the usual way of doing what you want is:

```
myChar = pgm_read_byte_near(&Image_1d_Array[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I thought the "i" in "(&Image_1_Array+i)"   was adding an offset of "i" to the Array not "i * Array size".   Big difference!!

Comment: @KenKloster: As a general rule, `(size_t)(&foo + i)` always means `(size_t)&foo + i * sizeof foo`. Note that `size_t` is just an integer type large enough to hold a pointer.